# Where is the explanation for all the Apache 2.4 "AH" codes?

Tags: apache-2.4

With Apache 2.4 httpd I am starting to see log messages like this:

```
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1521] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 ...
[core:notice] [pid 1521] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

I can infer the meaning of those two, but I would like to have a source that lists *all* these "AH" codes and their meanings. Where is that source?

Comment: We're not Apache developers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have a look here:

List of all errors present in the httpd source.

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ListOfErrors

A very long list indeed!

Comment: And with over a thousand of the things, **far** too big to quote here, too!

Answer (score 1):

As in [Diamond's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/751385/236916), the [Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ListOfErrors) is probably the first place to look, but if it's not been added there, you can try searching the source code for it.  AH error codes are referenced in the source code in a form like `APLOGNO(00163)`.

You can try a search on GitHub: https://github.com/search?type=code&q=repo:apache/httpd+APLOGNO(00163)

In this case it finds the line at [server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:1073](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/2891153/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c#L1073):

```
    ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_NOTICE, 0, ap_server_conf, APLOGNO(00163)
                "%s configured -- resuming normal operations",
                ap_get_server_description());
```

It might not directly tell you what caused the error, but the code in the surrounding context may help work it out.

More in-depth info about error tagging, and how httpd developers allocate new error tag numbers, can be found in this [README](https://github.com/apache/httpd/tree/trunk/docs/log-message-tags#readme).